# Nextcloud installation: Error while trying to create admin user

Tags: docker, nextcloud

I have created a mysql container like so:

`docker run --name nextcloud-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ABC -e MYSQL_DATABASE=nextclouddb -e MYSQL_USER=nextclouduser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=123 -d mysql:8`

I have also created a nextcloud container like so:

`docker run -d --network mynetwork --ip 192.168.1.227 --restart unless-stopped nextcloud`

In my browser I call up 192.168.1.227 and am greeted by the first run wizard.

I enter the following info:

- username: admin
- password: ***

MySQL/MariaDB:

- database user: nextclouduser
- database password: 123
- database name: nextclouddb
- database host: nextcloud-mysql

Result:

Error message:

> Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Any help in getting this cleared up would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nextcloud-mysql` and `nextcloud` containers in different networks.  Mysql I think in network `bridge`, nextcloud app in network `mynetwork`

You need to make both containers are on same network, add same network parameters to command for mysql containers as for application.example: `--network mynetwork --ip 192.168.1.228`

I think that `mynetwork` is your physical network and I'm not sure that docker can correctly resolve name `nextcloud-mysql` in your case, You may need to write IP address a database in application config.

Comment: Thank you very much. You could be on to something, my suspiscion was that this was an internal routing issue. In fact "mynetwork" is a Docker network I created. This is why I thought that both containers would be able to get the routing info "internally" within Docker. I will try to run both containers on "mynetwork" and see if that resolves it.

Comment: Posting back, that was it, now both containers are communicating with each other and I was able to install Nextcloud. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my install I renamed config.php to config.php.old

So the setup recreated it and it worked fine.